# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on my site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting this in chrome 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier' on line 5. I can't figure out whats wrong. Can anyone help please.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function(){
            jQuery("body").block(
                {
                    message: "<img class="lazy lazy-hidden" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=" data-lazy-type="image" data-lazy-src=\"https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif\" alt=\"Redirecting…\" style=\"float:left; margin-right: 10px;\" /><noscript><img src="https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Redirecting…" style="float:left; margin-right: 10px;" /></noscript>Thank you for your order. We are now redirecting you to Payment Gateway to make payment.",
                        overlayCSS:
                {
                    background: "#fff",
                        opacity: 0.6
              },
            css: {
                padding:        20,
                    textAlign:      "center",
                    color:          "#555",
                    border:         "3px solid #aaa",
                    backgroundColor:"#fff",
                    cursor:         "wait",
                    lineHeight:"32px"
            }
            });
            jQuery("#submit_payment_form").click();

            });
          </script>
```

Comment: You are missing ","somewhere. also, check your concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax highlighting makes it pretty clear, you're closing a quoted string and then continuing with the string:

```
message: "<img class="lazy lazy-hidden" src="data:ima...
```

The interpreter is seeing `lazy` as an identifier, and throwing an error because there is no such identifier.  Fix your quoting:

```
message: '<img class="lazy lazy-hidden" src="data:ima...
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape the slashes `/////` or it will be identified as a syntax error because `//` is a comment in javascript

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp

Comment: This is misleading.  If the string is properly escaped, the forward slashes do not need to be.  `//` is perfectly valid within a Javascript string, and will not be interpreted as the start of a comment.